# Changing the TextView color depending on the progress of a SeekBar

Tags: android, xml, colors, textview, seekbar

I am trying to change the color of the `TextView` depending on the `SeekBar`'s progress as following:

- 0-25% -> green
- 25%-50% -> yellow and so on...

When I using the following code, the `TextView` doesn't show the value anymore.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

**Code:**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) 
{   
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress + "%"));
    if(progress >= 25 && progress < 50)
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.Yellow);
    else if(progress >= 50 && progress < 75)
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.Orange);
    else if(progress >= 75 && progress <= 100)
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
    else 
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.Green);
}
```

---

**XML:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tvProgress"
    android:textColor="@color/Green"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
```

Comment: Does it give any error? Are you sure of the strings R.color.Yellow, R.color.Orange and R.color.Red having proper hex values?

Comment: it looks like you are not updating the textview with setText. You have to do textView.setText(progress); in each if condition

Comment: That code should work without any problems. Are you sure you are setting the text + color on the right `TextView`?

Comment: @Sana - No, I am not getting any errors. Yes, the strings have proper hex values.

Comment: @Luksprog - Yes, it's the right TextView; I've double checked it.

Comment: @Andro Selva - I surely thought that was the problem, still no value! Yet if I just use textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress + "%")), it will work properly, but not with the color thing, only the default color I've given it in the begining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what the problem is, but I worked on it and it works very fine for me. I have attached the screen shots of the out put also. Please check.

**main.xml**

```
 <ScrollView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView  android:id="@+id/aksharTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="afadjklhfg"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/arialTextView"/>



            <SeekBar  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/aksharTextView"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"/>
     </RelativeLayout>


 </ScrollView>
```

**onCreate()**

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                aksharTextView.setText(progress+"");
                if(progress >= 25 && progress < 50)
                    aksharTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                else if(progress >= 50 && progress < 75)
                    aksharTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                else if(progress >= 75 && progress <= 100)
                    aksharTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else 
                    aksharTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
```

**OutPut Screens**

[image: One]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually have the same code and to no end. I need to take a closer look cause surely it's a small thing that's escaping my eye.

Comment: try to use Color.BLUE, instead of R.color.blue. it might work. That's the only difference there