# Android : Changing color of an image using seekbar

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, seekbar

I want to Change color of an image on SeekBar OnProgress change event? I am showing an image in imageview and below that there is an SeekBar to change the color of an image.

I am using following way to change color of Imageview using seekbar

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        updateOuterColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
};
```

And updateOuterColor method will look something like this.

```
private void updateOuterColor() {
    seekR = seekBar1.getProgress();
    seekG = seekBar2.getProgress();
    seekB = seekBar3.getProgress();
    innerLips.setColorFilter(0xff000000 + seekR * 0x10000 + seekG * 0x100
            + seekB);
    eyeInnerOne.setColorFilter(0xff000000 + seekR * 0x10000 + seekG * 0x100
            + seekB);
    eyeInnerTwo.setColorFilter(0xff000000 + seekR * 0x10000 + seekG * 0x100
            + seekB);
}
```

Now the problem is when i am moving my seekbar this method overwrites my imageview. It means i am not able to see my imageview instead of that i can just see the different color over my image. I just want to apply that color on my image not over the image.

I have tried with some different code and android property but not able to figured it out.

If any one have idea then please help me...

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699810/how-to-change-bitmap-image-color-in-android

Comment: Hey A.S that code will change image directly. I want to set it with seekbar. So any idea how can i achieve this through seekbar.

Comment: just combine your and his code

Comment: Sry I think I do not really get your problem

Comment: porterduff with an alpha mask?

Comment: It's Okay, No problem, What i want to do is when i move my seekbar i want to change the color of my image which is set in imageview.

Comment: Sorry blackbelt, I am really not getting what you are trying to say...

Answer (score 1):

Update your onProgressChanged method like this

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

                if(progress >= 25 && progress < 50)
                  // set color on image here
                else if(progress >= 50 && progress < 75)
                  // set color on image here
                else if(progress >= 75 && progress <= 100)
                  // set color on image here
                else 
                  // set color on image here
            }
```

Also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047171/changing-the-textview-color-depending-on-the-progress-of-a-seekbar).

For changing Image  Color see this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android/1634199#1634199)

Comment: Thanks Brontok for your answer, But i am not getting that which property do i need to set for setting color on Imageview. Because if i use setColorFilter then it totally over writing my imageview means i am not able to see my image what i can see is color which i have applied over image.

Comment: Updated answer, check now.

Answer (score -2):

For this you have to first get each pixel of the image then you have edit each of its pixel